# Do we really need an unique provisioning profile for doing inapp payment for iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I understand we do need an unique APP ID, but seems I have tested and no matter for development and distribution, I can just use a wildcard provisioning profile for testing and app submission.

Anyone also experience this inconsistent behavior? Any drawback you can think of if I am using wildcard profile?

E.g. security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience in-app purchase works fine with wildcard app id, both in sandboxed environment and in the App Store.

But, it'd be better if you create a unique app id in order to use, for instance, push notifications.

Also, Apple can enforce the documented policy at any time, breaking your app. You won't have any rights to complain.